Use transaction builder to send USDC to multiple address
I make a monthly batch of USDC transfers to multiple addresses on Optimism. Nowadays I'm making each individual transaction and batching them, but they are a lot. Is there a way to make a JSON to input the transaction builder to do that? Can anyone help me to write it?
Thanks

You can look at this guide to know more about how to create batched transactions with the transaction builder.
If you are looking to implement an automated solution for this, you can take a look at this question which tackles it.
For more detailed explanations on how to use Safe{Wallet} UI, including the Transaction Builder or other apps, I suggest you visit help.safe.global and contact the dedicated support team there, by clicking on the message icon at the bottom right of the page.
Hope it helps, Louis
